# How to fix samsung galaxy note 9 stuck on set warranty bit recovery screen

Tags: updates, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-note-9

Please i need help, i tried to flash a firmware update to my note 9 using odin but it failed. Then the phone showed a blue screen asing to use smart switch. but i went and downloaded another firmware thinking that perhaps it was the firmware that was wrong and tried again and it still failed, this time the phone is stuck on samsung logo with the image of an open lock and a message saying "set warranty bit: recovery" i tried to get into download mode but no way. Please help

Comment: flash stock ROM from official download server https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My current issue is , it is currently stuck in "set warranty bit:recovery/kernel" when i try to boot into download mode it doesnt work it just stays on the set warranty screen.

Comment: so i wish to know how to remove it or bypass it or fix it such that i can set it to download mode and take it from there with odin

Comment: To enter Download mode, let battery drain completely until device is powered off for sure. Press and keep holding Volume Down (+ Home button if exist) while simultaneously connecting charger/usb cable

Comment: thanks @alecxs i will try that and get to you

Comment: I think it's called [Bixby](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-galaxy-note-9/download-mode) button